# Is collapsing a contractible closed subspace a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $Y \subset X$ be a closed, contractible subspace. Is the collapsing map
$$ \pi: X \rightarrow X/Y$$
a homotopy equivalence? If not, what is a counter example?

Comment: I think this is worth looking at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/can-contractible-subspace-be-ignored-collapsed-when-computing-pi-n-or-h-n?rq=1

Comment: In particular, Cheerful Parsnip's answer.

Comment: Yes, this is already answered at the previously linked question.